# Building Dependencies problem in Core-Plot integration?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I'm trying to integrate core-plot. I followed all the steps in "Read Me" doc in core-plot.
But i get a following error.

No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7).

I'm using IPhone simulator-4.1. x-code-3.2
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I figured it out. I changed to "All Configurations" in the project settings. Previously I was using Debug-device setting. For integration of Core-Plot Library , use 'All-Configurations' and set the your base sdks and additional sdk. Make sure your header search path is pointing core-plot framework(/**-recursive format). make changes both in Project build settings and Target build settings.
I changed from device to simulator. And Used appropriate additional libraries. I used LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler.